# Definition of these topologies

Tags: general-topology

(i)What is usual topology?

(ii)What is dictionary order topology?

Okay I am seeing this two terms in **James.E.Munkres**  so many times. But can't seem to find any definition anywhere. Can u tell me the definition of both thus term?? Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: The dictionary (or lexicographic) order is defined in Chapter 1 section 3. What qualifies as the "usual" topology depends on the set in question.

Comment: Oftentimes 'usual topology' means Euclidean, for example '$\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the usual topology', but it will depend on context.

Comment: There is dictionary order relation. But not any dictionary order topology in the section.

Comment: There is a question to prove that a given metric includes usual topology of $R^n$. Then what is the usual topology.

Comment: Every total ordering induces a topology. Munkres spends a whole section discussing this in Chapter 2.

Comment: Oh. OK. Thanks. What about the usual topology

Comment: As @DMcMor says, Munkres means the [Euclidean topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_topology) when he says the "usual topology." "Usual topology" almost always means the Euclidean topology when speaking of $\Bbb R^n$, but there is not a definition of the "usual topology on $X$" for an arbitrary set $X$.

Answer (score 0):

On the reals or more generally $\mathbb{R}^n$, the usual topoogy is the one induced by the Euclidean metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ or $d(x,y) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - y_i)^2}$ resp. On the reals this is the same topology as the order topology, (where all sets $(a,\rightarrow)$ an $(\leftarrow, a)$ are open) which he spends a whole section on early in the book IIRC.

For a product of ordered sets $(X,<_X)$ and $(Y,<_Y)$ , the lexicographical (or dictionary) ordering of the orders is defined (by $((x,y) <_l (x',y')$ iff $x <_X x'$ or $x = x'$ and $y <_Y y'$; like in a dictionary where the first letter determines the order first), and the topology this order induces is the dictionary order topology, of course.

On the plane this induces the same topology as $\mathbb{R}$ in the discrete topology times $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology (in their product topology). This is one of his exercises (proofs of which can be found on this site).